# knockout subscribe to select firing inconsistently with KendoUI

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have a select control where I have a subscription. When I do not apply the kendo styles, the control works as expected, the subscription code fires once and does not refire onBlur or for any other reason. When I do have kendoDropDownList applied, the subscription behaves *consistently erratic*.

```
$("select").kendoDropDownList();
```

The erratic behavior is select a value, the subscription fires. click another control, the subscription event fires again and the value is undefined, even though the select control is showing the value as unchanged. Subsequent selections do fire the subscription as expected.
Using the down/up arrow on a select control also doesn't fire when using kendo.

```
<select id="newExperienceFrequency"   data-bind="value: frequency, options: $root.controls.frequencies,  optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Select', event: { mouseover: mouseoverFrequency, mouseout: mouseoffFrequency }" class="select frequencyTip" title="foo"></select>


    self.proficiency.subscribe(function () {
        self.proficiencyId = self.proficiency();
        console.log('proficiency subscribed: ' + self.proficiency());
        my.setCounterHint($("#newExperienceFrequency").val(), self.proficiency());

        var tip = "Don't just list those skills your strongest in. It's just as important to add new skills you are aquiring!";
        var result = $.grep(my.ajaxData.member.Proficiencies, function (e) { return e.Id == self.proficiency(); });
        if (result.length == 0) {
            // not found
        } else if (result.length == 1) {
            // access the foo property using result[0].foo
            tip = result[0].Name + ':\nAutonomy: ' + result[0].Autonomy + '\nContext: ' + result[0].nContext + '\nKnowledge: ' + result[0].Knowledge + '\nWorkmanship: ' + result[0].Workmanship;
        } else {
            // multiple items found
        }
        $(".proficiencyTip").attr('title', tip).attr('alt', tip);
        $(".proficiencyQuestionMark").fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

Is this a known issue, or am I simply doing something wrong? Am I making more work for myself by trying to use Kendo with Knockout? Would these issues go away if I just used kendo and dropped knockout?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as versed with KendoUI as I am with knockout.  But if I had to guess it would be that kendo is triggering a changed event on the element which is causing knockout to fire more than it normally would.

I would recommend giving your subscription a parameter for the new value rather than refering to `self.proficiency()` in the subscription.  Then you can check if the value is defined in the subscription.

Also, i recommend reevaluating a way to avoid doing jquery in your viewmodel.  If you must perform jquery make a custom animation or a new binding.  More than likely you can bind your Ui to another property in your VM and decouple your view/vm.

For example the the questionmark element could be bound to a boolean observable.  Make a custom binding fadeVisible. I vaguely remember the documentation having a sample for that.  Its not difficult to make.  (hint: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html)

```
self.proficiency.subscribe(function(val) {
    if (typeof(val) === 'undefined')) {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent observations! I'm pretty new to Knockout (and web 2.0 as a whole) and will take a look at your link. As it turns out, I found the answer leveraging ryan niemeyer's   bindings for Kendo http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/web/DropDownList.html